# Is it possible to fail Jenkins pipeline when triggered processes have failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `try {} catch (err) {}` clause in my jenkins ci/cd pipeline that deploys a `yaml` to CloudFormation in aws. However when I've tested this out and purposely made something incorrect on the yaml file, I can see the stack fails to upload in cloudformation but jenkins pipeline still carries on to next stage and eventually marks the build as successful which is not the desired outcome.

I wish to fail the pipeline completely if my cloudformation stack (or any external process) fails. How can I do this? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block, you can check for a specific error message and fail the build. SOmething like the below.

```
script {
   try {
        sh 'letsGenerateAError'
    }
    catch (error) {
      if(error.getMessage().contains("SOme Error you want to check")) {
        throw error
      }
        echo "Error occurred while Running, But ignoring it. Message : ${error.getMessage()}"  
    }
}
```